DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY error only in Android MAUI
I'm using Shell navigation to navigate from a Content Page to Shell page which contains TabBar. It is working perfectly on iOS but throwing MeasureSpec error in Android. I'm using .Net8.0.
First image which calls my AppShell page which has a MainPage.

Second image is of MainPage from which I'm calling my Shell Tabbar page.

Third image is my Shell page which contains Tab.


The NewTabbedPage is type of Shell. Did you mean you want to use Shell.Current.GotoAsync to navigate between two shell?

I created a new project to test the code you provided and reproduced this issue. Even though the navigation worked well on the Windows and iOS, I suggest you navigate from shell to another shell by setting MainPage. Such as:
private void OnCounterClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     App.Current.MainPage = new NewTabbedPage();
}

If you don't want to use new(), you can use the Dependency injection for it.
And for the DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY error, you can report it as a new issue on the github repo.

This will make the tabbed page as the root page of my app which I don't want to.

If so, you can put the <TabBar><Tab></Tab></TabBar> in the AppShell.xaml, make there is only one shell in your project. The error only appears when you navigate between two shells. @WasifMahmoodMustafa

New tabbed page is necessary as all the logic depends on it. Will see if I get a workaround.

If you get a workaround, you can share it as an answer. @WasifMahmoodMustafa
